# Web Service Navision The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized Error

Tags: asp.net, web-services, navision

i am trying to update a service reference on a Ms Dynamics Nav portal but getting the error.

```
      **This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.**

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
    <s:Fault>
    <faultcode xmlns:a="urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/error">a:System.NotSupportedException</faultcode>
    <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">RecordReference</faultstring>
    <detail>
    <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">RecordReference</string>
    </detail>
    </s:Fault>
    </s:Body>
    </s:Envelope>
```

In addition Most of the services are returning the  **The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.** Error, Any remedies?

Comment: that's a generic HTTP error message which means you aren't supplying whatever the necessary credentials are to access that resource.

Comment: I assume you are authenticating the request and the error is an unexpected NotSupportedException?